# setStatusBarOrientation: how to change the device orientation

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am using the follwoing code to change my portrait view to landscape view and it works fine.

But what i need to know is after changing the view to landscape, when i print the current orientation of the device it gives me "Portrait" mode.

Can this code change the device orientation? if so then why it shows as "Portrait" Mode when i check the current orientation?

So how can i change the device orientation in the documented way?

Kindly help me out...

Please have a look at my code below

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
CGFloat screenWidth = screen.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screen.bounds.size.height;
UIView *navView = [[self navigationController] view];
navView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
navView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
navView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
navView.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2.0, screenHeight/2.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the device orientation did not changed ! You just manually set the **statusBar** orientation and apply a transform on your **view** !

Comment: So how can i change the device orientation in the documented way?

Comment: Short Answer : by rotating the device, that's all ;-)